# In Excel VSTO, how can I check if a worksheet belongs to a closed workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto, comexception

If I have a reference to `Worksheet` and I close it's parent `Workbook`, the reference doesn't go away. But I can't figure out how I should check to make sure these sheets don't exist. Checking for `null` doesn't work.

Example:

```
Workbook book = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1]; // Get first worksheet
book.Close(); // Close the workbook
bool isNull = sheet == null; // false, worksheet is not null
string name = sheet.Name; // throws a COM Exception
```

This is the exception I get when I try to access the sheet:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  HResult=-2147221080
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401A8
  Source=MyProject
  ErrorCode=-2147221080
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.get_Name()
       at MyCode.test_Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) in c:\MyCode.cs:line 413
  InnerException:
```

This wouldn't even be an issue if I could check for a workbook delete event, but Excel doesn't provide one (which is *really* annoying).

Is there some convenient way to make sure I don't use these worksheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other solutions fail, another way to handle this is to store the name of the workbook after it opens, then check to see if that name exists in the `Workbooks` collection before referencing the sheet. Referencing the workbooks by name will work since [you can only have uniquely named workbooks in each instance of Excel](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/01/07/why-can-t-i-open-two-files-with-the-same-name.aspx).

```
public void Test()
{
    Workbook book = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    string wbkName = book.Name; //get and store the workbook name somewhere
    Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1]; // Get first worksheet
    book.Close(); // Close the workbook
    bool isNull = sheet == null; // false, worksheet is not null
    string name;

    if (WorkbookExists(wbkName))
    {
        name = sheet.Name; // will NOT throw a COM Exception
    }
}

private bool WorkbookExists(string name)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbk in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks)
    {
        if (wbk.Name == name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit: for completeness, a helper extension method:

```cs
public static bool SheetExists(this Excel.Workbook wbk, string sheetName)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= wbk.Worksheets.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((Excel.Worksheet)wbk.Worksheets[i]).Name == sheetName)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works, but only if I happen to have the `Workbook` at the time. My example code was simple, but in practice, I have several methods which only take a `Worksheet` object. Nevertheless, I'm going to accept your answer since I ended up doing something similar. Namely, I checked `Application.Workbooks.Count > 0`. Since I only ran into this issue when there were no workbooks open, this check sufficed for my needs. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 3):

I use this method :

```
        private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

or you can try something like this:

```
    static bool IsOpened(string wbook) 
{ 
    bool isOpened = true; 
    Excel.Application exApp; 
    exApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); 
    try 
    { 
        exApp.Workbooks.get_Item(wbook); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        isOpened = false; 
    } 
    return isOpened; 
}
```

Comment: How do I know when to call this though? I have some potentially open or potentially closed worksheet. If it's open I want to do something with it. If it's closed I don't. The problem is I have no way of knowing if it's open or closed. This method seems like it will help only if I know it's closed.

Comment: I can do this, but I'd rather only use it as a last resort. I'm generally of the opinion that [exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control)

Comment: I agree, but I don't think you will use this method a lot, so it should not impact your application performance.
In addition, I tried :) Hopefully you will be able to come up with better solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but you could check if the Workbook `sheet.Parent` exists in the Application.Workbooks collection.

Comment: Won't work. Calling `sheet.Parent` causes the same exception as calling `sheet.Name`. Good thought though.